# getLongExtra always return default value using PendingIntent

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle, android-pendingintent, extras

I want to pass a long value using a PendingIntent something like this

```
Intent intentForPending = new Intent(context, NewBlaBlaActivity.class);
long courseId = 15252;
intentForPending.putExtra("courseId", courseId);
intentForPending.putExtra("isFromPushNotification", true);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intentForPending, 0);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
        context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.appicon)
        .setContentTitle("BlaBla")
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
        .setContentText(message)
        .setAutoCancel(true);


mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

And get the value as below

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if(intent.getBooleanExtra("isFromPushNotification", false)) {
    long courseId = intent.getLongExtra("courseId", 0);     
}
```

But I always get 0 from the intent. The weird thing is while I can get the boolean value with 'isFromPushNotification' key from the intent, I cannot get the long value from the same intent.

This drives me crazy. As you can see, it is a PushNotification and this code runs when I tap on the notification.

I tried all the way I can get from the forums and questions in stackoverflow, adding L suffix on def and original value on long objects. But I think PendingIntent is wet blanket.

I am waiting for your godlike advices. Thanks!

Comment: does intent.getIntExtra("courseId", 0) return 15252?

Comment: what does `intent.hasExtra( "courseId" )` return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to use extras with a `PendingIntent`, always use a flag in the last parameter of the `PendingIntent` factory method (`getActivity()` in your case). Probably you want [`FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT), to indicate to replace any existing `PendingIntent` contents with the new extras.

Comment: Now that's the godlike answer. Thanks!